# Getting exception while using JAX-RS response class to return the entity

Tags: java, tomcat, jax-rs

When I use the below code I get the exception. It looked to be jar issue, to conform it I uncommented the commented code and it worked fine.

Message class is annotated with @XmlRootElement, so that should not be an issue as well.

getting exception - org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=class java.util.ArrayList.

```
@Path("/messages")
@Singleton
public class MessageResource {

MessageService service = new MessageService();

@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response getMessages(@BeanParam MessageBean bean) {

    List<Message> messages;

    if (bean.getYear() > 0)
        messages = service.getMessagesForYearById(bean.getYear());
    messages = service.getMessages();

    return Response.ok().entity(messages).build();
}

// @GET
// @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
// public List<Message> getMessages(@BeanParam MessageBean bean) {
//
// List<Message> messages;
//
// if (bean.getYear() > 0)
// messages = service.getMessagesForYearById(bean.getYear());
// messages = service.getMessages();
//
//
// return messages;
// }
```

}

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servletclass>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>testing.jaxrs.Messages</param-value>
        </init-param>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Did you add `jersey-json` to your dependencies? Please post your web.xml as well.

Comment: I have jersey-bom, jersey-container-servlet-core, jersey-media-moxy added as dependencies in pom.xml.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
List<Message> messages 
Response.ok().entity(messages)
```

This leads to a type loss carried by the Collection due to type erasure at runtime. Wrap the collection with [GenericEntity](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/ws/rs/core/GenericEntity.html) to preserve its type information:

```
GenericEntity generic = new GenericEntity<List<Message>>(messages){};
return Response.ok().entity(generic).build();
```

Comment: Thanks @grizzly. That worked, as I just started learning JAX-RS,  and was not aware about GenericEntity. Let me  explore more about it.